# Как создать страницу постов?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование

У меня имеется страница posts в ней я через editor создаю посты. Так вот, как сделать, чтобы посты были /posts/тут_пост? Расскажите по подробнее. В настройках я выбрал в качестве постов страницу posts. Но как дальше? Нужно чтобы была стр /posts/privet-new-post

Comment: Ты и рассказываешь не понятно и всё делаешь неправильно. Какие такие страницы post, editor, посты в страницах. и пр. Создавать можно страницы и записи. https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B

Comment: @SeVlad он хочет, чтобы у него слаги для стандартных постов формировались так же, как слаги постов кастомного типа.

Comment: @KAGGDesign это один из возможных вариантов. А может у него катомный тип записи. Или ещё какая-то непонятная фигня с плагинами (судя по какому-то editor). Так гадать можно долго.